# How to write UTF-8 symbols in JSP with Struts 2

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, struts2, character-encoding

I have a list in my action which I field by values saved on a MySql DB.

I only have one object stored, which has designation `€`.

In JSP when I do this:

```
<s:iterator value="unitesList">
    <s:property value="designation"/>
</s:iterator>
<s:select list="unitesList" name="unity" listValue="designation" listKey="id" />
```

I have this:

```
€
<select name="unity" id="unity">
    <option value="1">?</option>
</select>
```

Why on `<s:select>` element the `€` element is transformed in a `?` ?

Comment: What is the page encoding or content type?

Comment: The page encoding is not defined

Comment: @tviana any reason to not upvote the answers ?

Comment: No reason, just my bad.. you're right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this on the top of the JSP page. Symbols in UTF-8 encoding displays better than `?`.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: ok, I see but why `<s:property value="designation"/>` displays correctly and `<s:select>` don't? And that did not solve the problem..

Comment: Struts UI tags escape symbols before they are written to the out.

Comment: there is other alternative over the `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>` solution?

Comment: sorry, where do I put `escapeHtml="false"`?

Comment: put it on property tag, it has this attribute. By default it's set to `true` that is why you see this symbol and we don't see how it's rendered. But at the moment we don't understand it, because it's printed unescaped.

Comment: The `property` tag escapes the symbol to `&euro;` select tag doesn't escape it, and if your page is not UTF-8 encoded it will be printed as ASCII character results to `?`.

Answer (score 1):

If the page encoding is not defined, the default is (the equivalent of the JSP `page` directive):

```jsp
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
```

The encoding you want is not `ISO-8859-1`, but `UTF-8`, that supports any language (take a look at [Table 23-2 Valid Values for the IANA-Defined Character Set](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_nls003.htm)).

You can set your page, request and response encoding in three ways:

1. Setting the `contentType` in each JSP:

   ```jsp
   <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
   ```
2. Setting the `pageEncoding` in each JSP:

   ```jsp
   <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
   ```
3. Setting the `<jsp-property-group>` once in web.xml:

   ```jsp
   <jsp-config>
       <jsp-property-group>
           <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
           <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>            
       </jsp-property-group>
   </jsp-config>
   ```

The HTML `<meta>` tag will be generated accordingly. Remember to not specify different encodings when unnecessarily using both `pageEncoding` and `<jsp-property-group>`, it is a translation-time error.

For more info about this, read the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebI18N5.html) (pretty old, but still true).